# Query interceptors: Change response status code

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

Is it possible to change the HTTP status code returned by WCF Data Services when one of the query interceptors return false?

As a bonus, is there a way to selectively return different status codes depending on the query interceptor that failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was really looking for the [Processing Pipeline](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2010/07/19/odata-and-authentication-part-4-server-side-hooks.aspx).

For reference, an identical question can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/960d34d7-6aa2-4fd7-b067-35b637e5430c/how-can-i-override-wcf-to-return-status-code-401-not-authorized?forum=adodotnetdataservices). The same concerns and solution are also expressed [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/06/03/10482.aspx) and [there](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/07/20/wcf-dataservices-amp-the-processing-pipeline.aspx), respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like the following to access the current service method and change the returned HTTP method header information

```
WebOperationContext operationContext = new WebOperationContext(OperationContext.Current);
operationContext.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
```

Comment: That's a really nice idea.  Unfortunately, and unless I'm doing something wrong, it doesn't seem that the OperationContext API (which I'm unfamiliar with) is used by WCF-DS.  In any case, I'm still receiving a 404.  FTR, I placed it in the QI itself, and verified that it was indeed executed at each request (I originally thought WCF DS would execute them once at the beginning to pre-generate the SQL queries).

Comment: Sorry dude, that classed worked for me. There is also the HTTPWebResponse class which is in the System.Net library that could help you build a dynamic response object.

Comment: When I look at the outgoing response object in the query interceptor, it seems that it's still merely [initialized with default values](http://pastebin.com/Sb4uyFcW) at [this point](http://pastebin.com/apcviAHC).  Is this normal behavior?  If so, how would WCF-DS know which properties to use or not if we only modify one (status code)?  Thanks for the HTTPWebResponse suggestion, I've looked at it, and I think overriding the response generated by WCF-DS would kind of defeat the purpose of a query interceptor.  In retrospect, QIs might not be what I want, I just don't have a real alternative.