# Force wcf odata service to send Success status code 200

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7, odata

I am currently using a wcf odata web service with entity framework. My code returns an internal server error (500) while performing post operation from edmx file. But the data gets posted because I am performing insert/update operation using queries later in code.

I want to force return a success status code 200 and skip this "500 status code (internal server error). An error occurred while processing this request" since my functionality works well.

How can I achieve this? Any suggestion?

Comment: If you get an `HTTP 500` error, most likely your code throws an exception somewhere. To force your code to return an `HTTP 200` guard your application with `try/catch`, eliminate any errors and return `Ok` at the end of your controller code.
You really first check where your code throws an exception, or at least inspect the HTTP error message if you can see something in the stack trace if it is enabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125558/query-interceptors-change-response-status-code

Comment: I am using views in edmx file.While performing post operation using the view i get 500 error.But i want to override that and return success code 200. i am just using them to get data from rest client body and performing a post operation using code and queries.I dont get any error or exception in my code.